# Is there an easy way to make an API call that has OAuth2.0

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I am at a complete loss at this point with oauth2.0.

For all of our automated API testing we have only had to handle basic auth (passing in the user / pass into the request) but they have just switched over to oauth2.0 with no warning so now all of our API tests are failing.

I can't seem to find an example of how to do a call with this type of auth that isn't multiple steps / convoluted. Granted I don't really know anything about oauth2.0 so it's probably just me.

The instructions we were given shows us how to create a collection in Postman, add in some values to this collection, and then we're able to just generate a token from that. The main problem is that one of their calls prompts the user to enter a username / password in a form so it can generate the token. This seems like a step I'd like to avoid having to do in an API test if possible.

I was looking at this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) and it looks like I can get away with making 2 separate calls - the first to generate the auth code and the 2nd call that would take in that code to generate the token - but the dev team said they can't provide us with the challenge_code or a way to generate one as they're auto-generated for them.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Are you able to make these types of calls with this auth without having to enter credentials into a form?

Comment: Does the OAuth flow they've configured support non-interactive grants? Authorization code implies a user being present, which you don't want for an API. Can you use client credentials?

Comment: @CodeCaster i just asked a dev and they had no idea about the grant so im assuming that its not supported. the only credentials that it looks like i can use are the ones i have to manually enter into the form when its prompted